# Problema de conexion con QR a una red wifi Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, wifi

tengo una app en android studio en el que quiero conectarme al esp32 por medio de wifi el esp32 crea un softAP con el ssid Healthywater y la contraseña ID000001 y estos datos los genero en un QR El problema es que a pesar de que el QR tenga la informacion valida y el esp32 genere bien la red con esas credenciales (que ya lo probe usando el lector de qr nativo de android y conectandome a la red) siempre me da el mismo error (Failed to add/get network ID) ese es el mensaje que imprimo en el logcat cuando falla mi app , y este es mi registro [IMAGEN DE REGISTRO LOGCAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omsLL.png)

Estoy desesperado necesito ese metodo de conexion para enviar datos entre android studio y el esp32 ya que es el prototipo de un producto y es la forma mas accesible para el usuario escanear un QR y que se envien datos enre los dispositivos por wifi para configurar el esp32, si alguien me pudiera ayudar o dar alguna recomendacion para lograr esto Gracias aqui esta mi codigo:

```
public class Configurar_dispositivo extends AppCompatActivity  {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CHANGE_WIFI_STATE = 123;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 456;


    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiConfiguration wifiConfig;
    private TextView texto_bienvenida;
    private ConstraintLayout opciones_configurarcion, conectando_a_dispositivo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configurar_dispositivo);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        texto_bienvenida = findViewById(R.id.bienvenida);
        opciones_configurarcion = findViewById(R.id.opciones);
        conectando_a_dispositivo = findViewById(R.id.conectando);
        conectando_a_dispositivo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Button iniciar_scaneo = findViewById(R.id.btn_qr);
        texto_bienvenida.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        opciones_configurarcion.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        animacion();

        iniciar_scaneo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkWifiPermission();
            }
        });
    }

    private void animacion() {
        texto_bienvenida.setTranslationX(-200);
        texto_bienvenida.setAlpha(0.0f);
        texto_bienvenida.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        opciones_configurarcion.setTranslationY(300);
        opciones_configurarcion.setAlpha(0.0f);
        opciones_configurarcion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ViewPropertyAnimator animatort = texto_bienvenida.animate()
                .translationX(0)
                .alpha(1.0f)
                .setDuration(1000);
        ViewPropertyAnimator animatorc = opciones_configurarcion.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .alpha(1.0f)
                .setDuration(1000);
        animatort.start();
        animatorc.start();
    }

    private void checkWifiPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Configurar_dispositivo.this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Tienes el permiso, procede con el escáner de QR
            desapareceranim();
        } else {
            // No tienes el permiso, solicítalo al usuario
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Configurar_dispositivo.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // El usuario concedió el permiso, procede con la operación
                desapareceranim();
            } else {
                // Permiso denegado, puedes mostrar un mensaje al usuario o tomar otras acciones
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    private void desapareceranim() {
        texto_bienvenida.setTranslationX(0);
        texto_bienvenida.setAlpha(1.0f);
        opciones_configurarcion.setTranslationX(0);
        opciones_configurarcion.setAlpha(1.0f);
        ViewPropertyAnimator animatort = texto_bienvenida.animate()
                .translationX(-300)
                .alpha(0.0f)
                .setDuration(1000);
        ViewPropertyAnimator animatorc = opciones_configurarcion.animate()
                .translationX(-300)
                .alpha(0.0f)
                .setDuration(1000);
        animatorc.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                texto_bienvenida.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                opciones_configurarcion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                new IntentIntegrator(Configurar_dispositivo.this)

                        .setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
                        .setPrompt("Escanea el codigo de tu Healtywather")
                        .initiateScan();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            }
        });
        animatort.start();
        animatorc.start();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Procesar el resultado del escáner
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() != null) {
                String qrContent = result.getContents();
                Log.d("WiFi Config", "QR Content: " + qrContent);
                connectToWiFi(qrContent);
            }
        }
    }

    private void connectToWiFi(String wifiInfo) {
        String[] parts = wifiInfo.split(";");
        String ssid = "";
        String password = "";
        for (String part : parts) {
            if (part.startsWith("S:")) {
                ssid = part.substring(2); // Ignorar "S:"
            } else if (part.startsWith("P:")) {
                password = part.substring(2); // Ignorar "P:"
            }
        }
        wifiConfig = isNetworkConfigured(ssid, password);
        // Verificar si la red ya está configurada
        if (wifiConfig != null) {
            handleWiFiConnection();
        } else {
            // Configurar la red y solicitar permisos si es necesario
            this.wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
            this.wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
            this.wifiConfig.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
            Log.d("WiFi", "SSID: " + wifiConfig.SSID);
            Log.d("WiFi", "PreSharedKey: " + wifiConfig.preSharedKey);
            // Verificar si tienes el permiso CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Tienes el permiso, procede con la operación
                handleWiFiConnection();
            } else {
                // No tienes el permiso, solicítalo al usuario
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
            }
        }
    }
    private void handleWiFiConnection() {
        try {
            int netId;
            if (wifiConfig.networkId == -1) {
                // La red no está configurada, agrégala
                netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                Log.d("WiFi", "Network added, netId: " + netId);
            } else {
                // La red ya está configurada, remuévela antes de agregarla nuevamente
                wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId);
                // Agrégala nuevamente
                netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                Log.d("WiFi", "Network already configured, netId: " + netId);
            }
            if (netId != -1) {
                boolean success = wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                if (success) {
                    // La red se habilitó correctamente
                    animacion_conectando();
                    Log.d("WiFi", "Network enabled successfully");
                    // Cambiar a la nueva red activada
                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();
                    // Activar el internet
                    // Este código es un ejemplo y puede variar según tu implementación
                    // Aquí deberías agregar el código para activar el internet
                    // Dependiendo del dispositivo y versión de Android, puede ser necesario
                    // utilizar ConnectivityManager y NetworkRequest para activar el internet.
                } else {
                    // No se pudo habilitar la red, mostrar Toast y log
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudo habilitar la red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("WiFi", "Failed to enable network");
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al agregar/obtener la red", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("WiFi", "Failed to add/get network ID");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("WiFi", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private WifiConfiguration isNetworkConfigured(String ssid, String password) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // El permiso no está concedido, solicítalo al usuario
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            return null;
        }

        List<WifiConfiguration> configuredNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

        for (WifiConfiguration existingConfig : configuredNetworks) {
            if (existingConfig.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"") && existingConfig.preSharedKey.equals("\"" + password + "\"")) {
                // La red ya está configurada
                return existingConfig;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void animacion_conectando() {
        conectando_a_dispositivo.setAlpha(0.0f);
        conectando_a_dispositivo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ViewPropertyAnimator animator = texto_bienvenida.animate()
                .alpha(1.0f)
                .setDuration(1000);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aquí hay una librería que lo hace más fácil https://github.com/ThanosFisherman/WifiUtils

Comment: En que sistema operativo estas presentando este problema? es emulador?

Comment: El problema lo estoy teniendo en el dispositivo real

Comment: Preguntaba "En que sistema operativo estas presentando este problema?"